# How to get Angular to show the correct validation message

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

In my angular page, I have a form:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="control-group" ng-class="{error:form.startDate.$invalid && form.startDate.$dirty && error:form.endDate.$invalid && form.endDate.$dirty}">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span4">
                <label><b>Start Date</b> (mm/dd/yyyy)</label>
                <input type="date" 
                        id="startDate"
                        name="startDate"
                        max="{{maxDate}}"
                        min="{{minDate}}"
                        ng-pattern="/^((\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})|(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4}))$/"
                        ng-model="startDate"
                        required />
            </div>
            <div class="span4">
                <label><b>End Date</b> (mm/dd/yyyy)</label>
                <input type="date" 
                        id="endDate"
                        name="endDate"
                        max="{{maxDate}}"
                        min="{{minDate}}"
                        ng-pattern="/^((\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})|(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4}))$/"
                        ng-model="endDate"
                        required />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span4">
                <span ng-show="form.startDate.$dirty">
                    <span ng-show="form.startDate.$error.required" class="help-inline">Start Date is required</span>
                    <span ng-show="form.startDate.$error.pattern" class="help-inline">Invalid start date</span>
                    <span ng-show="form.startDate.$error.max" class="help-inline">Start Date exceeds maximum</span>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="span4">
                <span ng-show="form.endDate.$dirty">
                    <span ng-show="form.endDate.$error.required" class="help-inline">End Date is required</span>
                    <span ng-show="form.endDate.$error.pattern" class="help-inline">Invalid end date</span>
                    <span ng-show="form.endDate.$error.max" class="help-inline">End Date exceeds maximum</span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="button" value="Load Report" ng-click="getLeads()" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</div>
```

The fields work as they should, but the validation does not. If I enter '02/30/2015' in either date field, it shows the required message instead of the invalid message.

So, the question is: How can I get the angular $dirty to validate the correct issue: the fields aren't empty, so "required" isn't valid. The date is bad, and should fire off the invalid message.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Side note - I highly recommend using the angular bootstrap datepicker in your case instead of your own input fields

Comment: These are the angular bootstrap datepicker. The "type=date" forces it to use the datepicker methodology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of Angular are you using, if you are using 1.3+ then you can use `ng-messages` for validation. https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessages

The issue you are running into is that both Required and invalid Pattern errors are throw and it is valid to be thrown. Because the value cannot be parsed it is `NULL` within the `ng view model`. What `ngMessages` does under the hood is interrogate the `$error` object and determine the true error. If you cannot use Angular 1.3 at this time, you could make your own directive to do something similar. Would be a better option than doing something such as `ng-show="$error.required && !$error.pattern"`, while that small expression solves your current case, you will run into more validation cases that would require special long expressions, which is why `ngMessages` was created.

Here is a Plunker that shows basic usage of ngMessages with your code
http://plnkr.co/edit/KaCiJPYaxqzhkSJNskc9?p=preview

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="control-group" ng-class="{error:form.startDate.$invalid && form.startDate.$dirty && error:form.endDate.$invalid && form.endDate.$dirty}">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span4">
                <label><b>Start Date</b> (mm/dd/yyyy)</label>
                <input type="date" 
                        id="startDate"
                        name="startDate"
                        max="{{maxDate}}"
                        min="{{minDate}}"
                        ng-pattern="/^((\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})|(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4}))$/"
                        ng-model="startDate"
                        required />
            </div>
            <div class="span4">
                <label><b>End Date</b> (mm/dd/yyyy)</label>
                <input type="date" 
                        id="endDate"
                        name="endDate"
                        max="{{maxDate}}"
                        min="{{minDate}}"
                        ng-pattern="/^((\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})|(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4}))$/"
                        ng-model="endDate"
                        required />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span4">
                <span ng-messages="form.startDate.$error" ng-if="form.startDate.$dirty">
                    <span ng-message="required">Start Date is required</span>
                    <span ng-message="pattern">Invalid start date</span>
                    <span ng-message="max">Start Date exceeds maximum</span>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="span4">
                <span ng-messages="form.endDate.$error" ng-if="form.startDate.$dirty">
                    <span ng-message="required">End Date is required</span>
                    <span ng-message="pattern">Invalid end date</span>
                    <span ng-message="max">End Date exceeds maximum</span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="button" value="Load Report" ng-click="getLeads()" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sadly we're on 1.1, and the upgrade so far has been... less than enjoyable. So this page is going to remain 1.1 for the time being.

Comment: @TJ Thanks! That answers the problem, for sure. Sadly, since this was 10 months ago, we've since bit the bullet and gone on a code-rampage, updating all our angular pages to 1.4. :)